# How to search for all upper & lowercase versions of a string in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm learning how to use the Twitter API using tweepy. I've produced a list of recent tweets with the keyword "tea garden" . From this list I want to search for strings in the tweets that include all capitalization variants of those strings.

## My initial list of tweets w/ keywords

```
public_tweets = api.search("tea garden", count=200)
```

## What do I add in this code to search for all upper/lowercase variants of the string? In this example, it would add tweets to the list that contained "Garden Tea" or "GARDEN TEA".

```
list = []

for tweet in public_tweets:
  if "garden tea" in tweet.text:
    list.append(tweet)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `str.lower` to convert it to lowercase first, then compare:

```
list = []

for tweet in public_tweets:
  if "garden tea" in tweet.text.lower():
    list.append(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str.upper` to convert it to uppercase first, then compare:

```
list = []

for tweet in public_tweets:
  if "GARDEN TEA" in tweet.text.upper():
    list.append(tweet)
```